# Choice between “à titre d'entraîneurs” and “en tant qu'entraîneur”

Tags: expressions, prépositions, nombres

Are “*en tant qu'entraîneur*” and “*à titre d'entraîneurs*” the correct translations for “*as a coach*” and “*as coaches*” respectively?

When do we need to use *en tant que* for saying *as a* preceding singular noun?
When do we need to use *à titre de* for saying *as* preceding plural noun?

Is it correct if I translate the following sentence

> He failed as a coach for the reason that other great players have failed as coaches: he thought about himself too much.

as

> *Il a échoué en tant qu'entraîneur pour la raison que d'autres grands joueurs 
>       ont échoué à titre d'entraîneur.*

Is there a better translation for that English sentence?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The idiomatic French would be:

> Il a échoué en tant qu'entraineur (précisément) pour la même raison que d'autres grands joueurs avant lui.

In English repetition is gracious, in French it's plain ugly, unless it isn't, don't ask.

When do we need to use *à titre de*? Hmm, *à titre de compensation*, *à titre de référence*, mais peut-être que je m'égare… *À titre de* usually implies exercise of rights or privileges associated to the profession, less so duties.

Both *à titre de* and *en tant que* follow the usual pluralization rules for adverbial groups. That is, you almost always want singular, except when it describes a plural noun and each entity acts accordingly to their own quality or title (then use plural).

Answer (score 9):

Usage of *à titre* is restricted to the cases where a more or less official title is needed to act (and *en tant que* will often be used in those cases).

If you want a close translation, it would be

> Il a échoué en tant qu'entraîneur pour la raison que d'autres grands joueurs ont échoué en tant qu'entraîneurs.

but the repetition doesn't feel natural.

Edit: see Stéphane's answer for something more idiomatic. What I wrote here feel clumsy when rereading.

Comment: I guess you meant "ont échoué en tant qu'entraîneurs".

Comment: @biozic, don't hesitate to edit out yourself this kind of errors.

Comment: I was told there weren't enough changed characters...

Comment: @biozic: You might want to upvote [this](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/92989/167500) (and to downvote the “accepted nonsense”).

Comment: @StéphaneGimenez: done, thanks for the tip!